# str_replace not replacing string with special character

Tags: php, xml, string

I am trying to read the docx file and replace the |* Pre Set *| words with user input. Having trouble replacing the words and not finding such words in string.

```
if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    echo "Cannot open $filename :( "; die;
}

$xml = $zip->getFromName('word/document.xml');


if(strpos($xml,'|*First Name*|')) {
    echo 'True';
} else {
    echo 'False';
}
//True;

if(strpos($xml,'|*Last Name*|')) {
    echo 'True';
} else {
    echo 'False';
}
//False

echo $xml;
//Hi! My name is |*First Name*| |*Last Name*|. My Email address is |*Email*|. My contact number is |*Contact Number*|.

$xml = str_replace('|*First Name*|', 'John', $xml);
$xml = str_replace('|*Last Name*|', 'Doe', $xml);

echo $xml;
//Hi! My name is John |*Last Name*|. My Email address is |*Email*|. My contact number is |*Contact Number*|.
```

This is the short script to replicate the problem. In this case, it works perfectly fine. It replaces the string. It found the word in string but I don't know why same thing is not happening in my main script which I read the docx file as xml files.

```
$old_string = "Hi! My name is |*First Name*| |*Last Name*|. My Email address is |*Email*|. My contact number is |*Contact Number*|.";

if(strpos($old_string,'|*First Name*|')) {
    echo 'True';
} else {
    echo 'False';
}
//True

if(strpos($old_string,'|*Last Name*|')) {
    echo 'True';
} else {
    echo 'False';
}
//True

$old_string = str_replace('|*First Name*|', 'John', $old_string);
$old_string = str_replace('|*Last Name*|', 'Doe', $old_string);

echo $old_string;
//Hi! My name is John Doe. My Email address is |*Email*|. My contact number is |*Contact Number*|
```

Comment: then what is the problem?, it replaces the words on string fine.

Comment: @BeingSunny when I tried the same thing on the xml file. it doesn't work as you can see in the first script

Comment: @Parfait This docx reading script is that I found on internet. I tried echo out the type of the $xml and found out that it is string of the content which is inside the docx file. I am sorry that I am at beginner stage to explain you in detail.

My desired result is 
`$string = 'My name is |*Name*|'`
`replace |*Name*| with user input`